# Error Accessing Bluemix Node-RED Editor

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red

I'm using Node-RED Starter to build my app. My app URL can be accessed [here](https://PROJECT_NAME.mybluemix.net/).

[image: This]

should appear on my browser, but I got an

[image: error] instead.

The app however seems to be working fine on my dashboard. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thank you.

Comment: Please describe what the actual error is, rather than just posting a picture

Comment: I haven't got any errors from the log. Just the page not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app is throwing a 500 error which basically means that your app is very much broken. How did you build it? Which starter did you use?

As you are running in the IBM Cloud, I would drop what you already have, and recreate using the starter from the IBM Cloud catalog. Unless of course if that is what you used to create it in the first place. In which case as per the other suggestions look at the server side logs, from the options on IBM Cloud for your application.